# How to include user specific access to Django REST API in this example?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

My understanding of authentication via an API is that the HTTP request sent by the client needs to include credentials, whether that be just a raw username and password (probably bad practice) or a hashed password, token, etc.

Normally in my Django views, I just use:

```
request.user.is_authenticated():
```

If I want my API to be used with an iOS app, this line of code cannot be used because it relies on sessions/cookies?

I would like to edit the following function, to allow it access to a specific user:

```
api_view(['GET'])
@csrf_exempt
def UserInfoAPI(request):
    ###if HTTP header includes name and password:###
        private_info = Entry.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = EntrySerializer(private_info, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Is there a simple way to manually check for a username/pass in the HTTP header?  I don't actually plan to use this in a production environment, but for the sake of understanding, I would like to understand how to have this function verify a username/pass from the http header.

Comment: On a side note, you can use `TokenAuthentication` scheme for your Ios app.

Answer (score 2):

Django REST Framework tries to determine the user that sends the request looking into the `Authorization` HTTP header. What you should send inside this header depends on the authentication scheme you choose. For example, if you choose `BasicAuthentication`, your header would be:

```
Authorization: Basic <"user:password" encoded in base64>
```

or, if you choose `TokenAuthentication`:

```
Authorization: Token <your token>
```

I would recommend the [`TokenAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) scheme. More schemes are listed in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

To make sure only authenticated users have access to that API's endpoint, use the [`IsAuthenticated`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) permission. This will check your user's credentials in the request, and if they are not correct, it will raise a `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` error.

Your Django REST Framework view would look something like this:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class UserInfo(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Entry
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(UserInfo, self).get_queryset()
        user = self.request.user
        return queryset.filter(user=user)
```

As for the code in your iOS app, [this post](http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/http-basic-access-authentication-with-objective-c-and-ios) may be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure that this answers my question.  Does IsAuthenticated check for an HTTP header of username/pass?

Comment: Depends on the selected authentication back-end, but yes, you can say it does. Is your problem on the back-end (DRF) or on the iOS client ?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain a little more about how DRF determines the request's user. I hope it helps!

Comment: I added an iOS-specific post about the `Authorization` header as well.

Comment: In response to the update post, when you say "checks user credentials in request", it really is only checking the user or user id, not the password right?  Also, I am trying to manually code my function to check the http header for username and pass

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but basically I want to manually write a username password authentication check in this function and then ultimately i would like to be able to CURL this URL passing username/pass credentials in the HTTP header

Comment: No, no, DRF determines the user depending on the content of the `Authorization` header. You should send this header in every request. So if you send `Authorization: Basic username:password`, and the password is correct, `request.user` inside the DRF will be your user called `username`.

Comment: So you don't need to write an authentication check in your function, the built-in DRF authentication schemes already do that for you.

Comment: So, yes, once you have your `Authentication` scheme set, you can do `curl http://yourhost/yourendpoint/ -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic <user:password encoded in base64>'` to get the entries.

Comment: what is "password encoded in base64" ?  When I run this curl command can I just type the raw password ?